# Extract email address from outlook for a list of employee ids

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I am almost done with the code, however I'm only able to pull a single employee ID id. Refer to the code below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton24_Click()
Dim outApp As Object 'Application
   Dim outTI As Object 'TaskItem
   Dim outRec As Object 'Recipient
   Dim outAL As Object 'AddressList

    Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    Set outAL = outApp.Session.AddressLists.Item("Global Address List")
    Set outTI = outApp.CreateItem(3)

    outTI.Assign
    Set outRec = outTI.Recipients.Add(Range("A2").Value)
    outRec.Resolve
    If outRec.Resolved Then
        Range("B2").Value = outAL.AddressEntries(outRec.AddressEntry.Name).GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
    Else
        MsgBox "Couldn't find Employee"
    End If

End Sub
```

Looks like some changes need to be made in this code so that I can extract email address from the list.

```
Set outRec = outTI.Recipients.Add(Range("A2").Value)
```

Comment: Need to extraxt email address for list of employee ids

Answer (score 0):

If your list is on Column A then Try looping through column

Example

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton24_Click()
    Dim olApp As Object 'Application
    Dim olTaskItem As Object 'TaskItem
    Dim olRecip As Object 'Recipient
    Dim olAddList As Object 'AddressList

    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    Set olAddList = olApp.Session.AddressLists.Item("Global Address List")
    Set olTaskItem = olApp.CreateItem(3)

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        olTaskItem.Assign

        Set olRecip = olTaskItem.Recipients.Add(Cells(i, 1).Value)

        olRecip.Resolve

        If olRecip.Resolved Then
            Cells(i, 2).Value = olAddList.AddressEntries(olRecip.AddressEntry.Name).GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
        Else
            MsgBox "Couldn't find Employee"
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```